# Inserting a border for the whole page

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderRight) 
 .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle 
 .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt 
End With
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft) 
 .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle 
 .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt 
End With
```

Im new at VBA, and didnt find methods or misinterpreted them. I want to create a border for the whole page (Left and Right) Code above does it only for the singe Line

Comment: Your first step should be to record a macro whilst adding a page border. That will give you the objects and syntax you need to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code (from the macro recorder) shows the properties & methods you need. Amongst other things it shows that the is that your own code lacks the necessary Sections reference - all your code does is apply borders to what is actually selected - not to the underlying Section. Of course, depending on what you're trying to achieve, you're unlikely to need all of the code below - or you may need to use different parameters.

```
Sub Demo()
  With Selection.Sections(1)
    With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
      .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
      .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
      .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
      .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
      .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
      .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
      .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
      .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
      .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
      .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
      .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
      .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders
      .DistanceFrom = wdBorderDistanceFromPageEdge
      .AlwaysInFront = True
      .SurroundHeader = True
      .SurroundFooter = True
      .JoinBorders = False
      .DistanceFromTop = 24
      .DistanceFromLeft = 24
      .DistanceFromBottom = 24
      .DistanceFromRight = 24
      .Shadow = False
      .EnableFirstPageInSection = True
      .EnableOtherPagesInSection = True
      .ApplyPageBordersToAllSections
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Much obliged! Actually played with some of the those parameters, got what was looking for. Thank you!